# Emacs change to init.el

Tags: emacs, elisp

Basically, I have my configuration with a ~/.emacs.el and a ~/.emacs.d/, but I heard init.el is superior and more modern.

How can I migrate to init.el?

Comment: It's certainly superior if you like the entirely of your Emacs configuration to live within the `.emacs.d` directory, but that *is* the only benefit / reason to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `~/.emacs.el` into `~/.emacs.d/init.el`. Done.

Comment: To anyone else who's interested, ensure you don't just *copy* the file, as `~/.emacs` will take precedence if it exists.